# React Native: Multipart body must have at least one part

Tags: android, react-native, fetch-api

I've seen ["Multipart body must have at least one part"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591453/multipart-body-must-have-at-least-one-part) and I understand what it means, but I have no idea how to solve it.

We've got a React Native app, where it consumes a Swagger-autogenerated API client and at one point we make a POST request to an endpoint with no data. The endpoint *does* accept data though all the fields are optional and I should not send any data at that point.

On iOS, everything works perfect. On Android:

- If I'm on React Native Debugger (standalone one) + Enable Network Inspect, the API request works perfectly.
- If I'm on Vscode debugger, the request fails without even trying with the following error:

`Multipart body must have at least one part.`

*Without being able to change the SDK (as it's autogenerated from Swagger, and the actual HTTP request is many middlewares deep)*, how can I get rid of this problem? It should be possible as the same HTTP request works on iOS.

Answer (score -1):

Try to pass body as empty FormData in fetch function **body** parameter

**See Example**

```
var data = new FormData()

fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: data
});
```

Comment: I've already said that I don't have access to the SDK to change anything.